# Radio Button on the table is not selected after click with knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to apply the selection to a radio in a table, but after the click is not selected.

My code in table:

```
<td> <input type="radio" name="radioSelected"  data-bind = "click:$root.selectObjectRadio"></td>


$scope.selectObjectRadio= (obj) => {

    }
```

but the click is not leaving selected.

Comment: what selectObjectRadio method has?

Comment: @G_S 
it retrieves the selected object.

Comment: Can you post it and it would be better if you add a snippet showing your problem

Comment: @G_S is only a empty function.

Comment: @G_S updated.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[By default, Knockout will prevent the `click` event from taking any default action.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-click-action)

> However, if you *do* want to let the default click action proceed, just
>   return `true` from your `click` handler function.

I am wondering why you have a click binding on it at all, though.

Comment: I want get object of my table in click. i have a table with foreach, this radiobutton is a selection for object.what a viable way?

Comment: I would probably use the [`checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)